# Munkres, second half of Lemma 13.2

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Lemma 13.2 in Munkres says:

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each open set $U$ of $X$ and each $x \in U$, there is an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in C \subset U$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for the topology of $X$.

I'm going to denote the topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$. The first piece, proving that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis, is clear. I assume this is a basis "for some topology" on the *set* $X$ (so calling it a topological space is a slight abuse of notation) that we don't yet know is in fact $\mathcal{T}$, so we call it $\mathcal{T}'$. The next step is in proving $\mathcal{T}' = \mathcal{T}$.

The first direction $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$ is clear to me. The second direction is not. Munkres takes $W \in \mathcal{T}'$, and argues by Lemma 13.1, that since $\mathcal{T}'$ was generated by $\mathcal{C}$, $W$ can be written as a union of basis elements, i.e., of $C \in \mathcal{C}$. He then states that each $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$. This is the step I'm most unsure of, but I believe the argument is as follows. By the condition for openness in the topology generated by a basis, $C \in \mathcal{C}$ is surely open, so $C \in \mathcal{T}'$. But $\mathcal{T}' \subset \mathcal{T}$, as we just proved, so $C \in \mathcal{T}$. Is this the only way to argue this, or is there a more fundamental reason?

Assuming I have that fact, closure under unions gives the conclusion.

I'd appreciate if someone could look this over and let me know if I understand this proof properly.

Comment: $\mathcal C$ is a collection of open sets of $X$... that means exactly that any element of $C$ is in $\mathcal T.$

Comment: By $X$, it means the topological space $X$, not the set $X$, right? So open sets in the topological space means with respect to $\mathcal{T}$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, often the topology (i.e. the collection of open sets of $X$) is left nameless and we just refer to elements of the topology as "open sets of $X$". If we wanted to give the topology a name (as Munkres does in the proof once it becomes convenient to to so) the statement of the lemma could start "Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a topological space and let $\mathcal C\subseteq \mathcal T$ such that for all $U\in\mathcal T,$..."